# Multiple Aggregate functions in SQL

Tags: sql, count, distinct, aggregate-functions, pivot-table

I have several tables and I union them All and at the very end, I pivot them using COUNT Function.I have been trying to use COUNT DISTINCT instead of COUNT. But SQL gives me an error.

```
PIVOT(  
  COUNT ( DISTINCT ALL_Union_Table.Value) FOR  Label IN ([A],[B],C],[D],[E])
) As Final
```

Error I Face:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 140
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.

Plus, is it possible If I want to have them both? I mean is there any way to have multiple aggregate functions in pivot format in SQL?

Comment: You can use `distinct` in the subquery.

Comment: Consider changing this to two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Label, [Value]
FROM (
--foo1
Union
--foo2
union
--foo3
) AS ALL_Union_Table
PIVOT(  
  COUNT (ALL_Union_Table.Value) FOR  Label IN ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E])
) As Final
```

Not work out for you?

As for doing multiple aggregate queries on a pivot, I would instead do two separate (but similar) pivot queries and do a join between them.